# How to safely merge two ddrescue images

Tags: hard-drive, ddrescue

I have a damaged hard disk **hdbad** that I have run ddrescue on twice and saved to two different hard disk images **hdimg1** and **hdimg2** with:

```
$ sudo ddrescue -d -f -r3 hdbad hdimg1 mapfile1 
$ sudo ddrescue -d -f -r3 hdbad hdimg2 mapfile2
```

I now want to merge **hdimg1** onto **hdimg2** using the mapfile **mapfile1** of **hdimg1** as a domain mapfile like this:

```
$ sudo ddrescue -m mapfile1 hdimg1 hdimg2 mergemapfile
```

However when I do that I get the following message:

```
ddrescue: Output file exists and is not a regular file.
ddrescue: Use '--force' if you really want to overwrite it, but be
          aware that all existing data in the output file will be lost.
Try 'ddrescue --help' for more information.
```

I don't want to overwrite hdimg2, so it seems I shouldn't use --force. What should I do?